# Sqlite unrecognized token when inserting hash into db

Tags: sql, sqlite

Long story short for what im doing im hashing passwords and inserting them into a database.  Most of the time it works however I keep getting an unrecognized token error every once and a while and I cant figure out what's causing it.  Here's a particular case.

This is a statement that causes one of these errors

```
UPDATE Profiles SET Password = '|a¡è~©jÃQZ!ëg! (ªBìSóûÌõ»vî' WHERE UserName = 'ht999'
```

And this is the resulting sql error

```
(unrecognized token: "'|a¡è~©jÃQZ!ëg!")
```

any ideas on what about this string is causing the issue?

Comment: This question is wrong on multiple levels. Her's a few: I really doubt you have hardcoded this SQL in your program, which means it has been constructed by concatenating SQL keywords with data. This is prone to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), **DO NOT DO THAT!**. Secondly, you're storing passwords in clear text. Even though the password looks to be a really good one, you're missing a salt, which means you're not really storing a [hashed copy of the password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). **DO NOT DO THAT**

Comment: As for what is probably causing the specific error you're asking about, the encoding of the string you've input probably trips up the Sqlite parser. If you had used parameters instead of adding the password as a literal string, this problem would go away. **SO DO THAT!**

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot tell you how to use parameters with Sqlite, as this depends on the surrounding platform, programming language, Sqlite library, and probably other stuff. The exact syntax thus varies, depending on all of these, and probably more, factors.

Comment: **TL;DR**: Use parameters instead of injecting the values directly into the SQL statement text.

Comment: Hey Lasse, firstly thank you very much for the write up.  For the sake of brevity I truncated a lot of my code.  In my project essentially every time I create a password or reset one I generate a random salt which was concatenated with the password, and then I generated the hash which I then stored with the salt for later use.  Was this what you were describing or am I missing a step?  Also thanks for the heads up on using parameters, I see why its much better!  Also like you suggested it looks like changing the encoding of the string from ISO_8859_1 to base64 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is not actually with SQLite/ or the shown SQL but rather with whatever tool you are using to run the SQL or perhaps any preceding SQL should there be any (mybe an omitted **`;`** or perhaps en extraneous **`'`** or other enclosing character).

That is the SQL itself works (with Navicat, DB Browser for Sqlite, SQLite Manager, SQLite Studio) that is, the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Profiles;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Profiles (Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Password TEXT DEFAULT 'UNSETPASSWORD');
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Profiles (Username) VALUES 
    ('ht001'),('ht950'),('ht999');
SELECT * FROM Profiles;
UPDATE Profiles SET Password = '|a¡è~©jÃQZ!ëg! (ªBìSóûÌõ»vî' WHERE UserName = 'ht999';
SELECT * FROM Profiles;
```

Works on all the above and results in (as per Navicat):-

After the update :-

[image]

Before the update :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this Mike.  As you suggested the issue must not have pertained to that particular sql statement but how I formed it in my code.  I changed the encoding of the string to base64 to prevent any character like " ' " and ";" from appearing in the string and interfering with the syntax of the sql statement. It now works without issue, again thank you for the help.